# *ngFor com ngModel e value

Tags: html, ionic, angular

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de repetição:

**TS**

```
  resposta: string[];
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let pergunta of perguntas; let i = index">
```

Tenho um ngModel que preciso printar o valor dele em seu value:

```
<ion-textarea name="resposta" [(ngModel)]="resposta[i]" value="{{resposta}}" placeholder="Resposta" clearInput></ion-textarea>
```

Porém recebo:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Se eu fizer:
[(ngModel)] = "resposta" tudo ocorre bem, mas os meus outros elementos também recebem o valor que eu colocar nesse campo.

Comment: tenta colocar um *ngIf="resposta" no componente. Como o componente é iniciado vazio ele não possui a posição 0 do array.

`<ion-textarea *ngf="resposta" name="resposta" [(ngModel)]="resposta[i]" value="{{resposta}}" placeholder="Resposta" clearInput></ion-textarea>`

Comment: Mas ele precisa ser inicializado, mesmo que vazio, pois é um campo input...

Comment: Tenta inicializar ele com: 

`resposta: string[] = [""];`